# SQLite - Can not update a row that has a long text for id column

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql-update, android-sqlite

So i am working on this Inventory Management app on Android Studio and having a trouble adding a certain amount of product into the database. I have a method in my database class called `updateQuantity`. It is taking a barcode number and an amount to add, and it's supposed to update the products quantity.

```
private static final String TABLE_PRODUCT = "product";

private static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_BARCODE_NUMBER = "barcode_number"; // TEXT
private static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_QUANTITY = "quantity"; // INTEGER
private static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_NAME = "name"; // TEXT
private static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_PURCHASE_PRICE = "purchase_price"; //INTEGER
private static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_SALE_PRICE = "sale_price"; // INTEGER

public boolean updateQuantity(String barcode, int amount) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_PRODUCT + " SET " + COLUMN_PRODUCT_QUANTITY +
                   " = ((SELECT " + COLUMN_PRODUCT_QUANTITY + " FROM " +
                   TABLE_PRODUCT + " WHERE " + COLUMN_PRODUCT_BARCODE_NUMBER +
                   " = " + barcode + ") + " + amount + ") WHERE " +
                    COLUMN_PRODUCT_BARCODE_NUMBER + " = " + barcode;
    try {
        db.execSQL(query);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}`
```

It works with a product that has a barcode number "86938693" but does not do any quantity update for a product that has a barcode number "8690632034614". What is the problem here?

Comment: Maybe if you check the exception instead of just ignoring it, it would give you a hint about what's happening

Comment: Furthermore I doubt that query works for any case because you don't add any `'` around your strings. Maybe the system does some autoconversion to compare the string column to your given number (because without the ' your barcode is treated as number in the query) which fails when the number gets too big

Comment: Don't try to stick unknown string values directly in a SQL statement; bind the values to parameters instead. See your documentation for details.

Comment: It does not throw any exception and adding `'` to the sides of `barcode` did not change anything

Comment: So your method returns true? Are you sure a record with that barcode is contained in both tables? Does your barcode column have a fixed width?

Comment: It returns true for any product. There is only 1 table there, i forgot to change TABLO_URUN to  TABLE_PRODUCT while translating the code to English. If you mean string length by column width, it doesn't have fixt length, it's created as TEXT

Comment: If there is only one table, I refer to forpas' answer. If there is a row which matches the search condition, it will be updated (given that amount <> 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a very complicated sql statement, but it should be much simpler:

```
String query = 
    "UPDATE " + TABLE_PRODUCT + 
    " SET " + COLUMN_PRODUCT_QUANTITY + " = " + COLUMN_PRODUCT_QUANTITY + " + " + amount + 
    " WHERE " +  COLUMN_PRODUCT_BARCODE_NUMBER + " = '" + barcode + "'";
```

You don't have to search twice the table to get the value that you want to update. 
Also the value of the variable barcode must be enclose inside single quotes as it is a string.
If there is a case that the value of the column `COLUMN_PRODUCT_QUANTITY` is `NULL`, then you must use [`coalesce()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce):

```
String query = 
    "UPDATE " + TABLE_PRODUCT + 
    " SET " + COLUMN_PRODUCT_QUANTITY + " = coalesce(" + COLUMN_PRODUCT_QUANTITY + ", 0) + " + amount + 
    " WHERE " +  COLUMN_PRODUCT_BARCODE_NUMBER + " = '" + barcode + "'";
```

Comment: It was all about quantity values being NULL. The code below worked for me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

"86938693" could be converted into a long int but "8690632034614" could not.  I suspect that SQLite is doing an implicit conversion of the value you gave to what it normally expects for a primary key, which is long integer, regardless of what the column is defined as (yes, SQLite does that).  If your SQLite's primary key is defined on a column that is not a long integer, there are cases, like this one, where the table will be considered read-only and updates will fail.